# Bulma style overrides aren't working; Using Laravel 7.25.0

Tags: laravel, npm, sass, laravel-7, bulma

I've been using Bulma as a CSS framework for a site I'm building using Laravel, and for some reason, none of the overrides I've been writing have actually been taking place. In fact, if I remove everything from my app.scss file (including the line to import Bulma), nothing changes. I tried following the [docs](https://bulma.io/documentation/customize/with-node-sass/) given for node-sass, and when i try to execute the `npm css-build` command, I get the following error:

```
> @ css-build /Users/userName/Sites/siteName
> node-sass --omit-source-map-url sass/app.scss css/app.css

An output directory must be specified when compiling a directory
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ css-build: `node-sass --omit-source-map-url sass/app.scss css/app.css`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ css-build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I know this is probably a terribly worded question, but I'd appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction. I'm just genuinely lost.

app.scss:

```
@charset "utf-8";
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons");

// Variables
@import "_variables";

// Font Awesome
@import "font-awesome/scss/font-awesome";

// Bulma
@import "bulma/bulma";

// Bulma Vue Modules
@import "buefy/src/scss/buefy";

// Other SCSS Files
@import "overrides";
@import "helpers";
@import "manage";
@import "styles";
```

scripts portion of package.json:

```
"scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --disable-host-check --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "css-build": "node-sass --omit-source-map-url sass/app.scss css/app.css",
        "css-watch": "npm run css-build -- --watch",
        "start": "npm run css-watch"
    },
```

Comment: The key line to look for is this one: "An output directory must be specified when compiling a directory" I think you might need to do this in the webpack config file, or whatever system you're using that handles css files. Can you post the portion of your package.json that has the scripts? That might help troubleshoot.

Comment: Hi @rncrtr, I've added the scripts portion to the original post. Thank you for all your help!